# serverErrorCode: "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"

Tags: cloudkit

I have tried to call API by using Token and Container Name . I got Server error code for Authentication failed and  Reason have mentioned request needs authorization while calling in browser

https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/iCloud.test.Feedback/development/public/records/modify?ckAPIToken=xxxxxx8584574xxxx

I got Error

{ "uuid":"abc7575-jhfg956496-86886-fdf","serverErrorCode":"AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED","reason":"request needs authorization","redirectURL":"https://test.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/auth?oauth_token=xgfhfjf9869456985xxxx" }

Can anybody who have an idea about cloud kit js API .  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some CloudKit operations require user authentication. In addition to the ckAPIToken, you need to also include a session token (**ckWebAuthToken**=*[tokenValue]*) on the path.

If you're implementing the CloudKit Catalog authentication example, after a user authenticates, a token is saved as a browser cookie. In your case, the name of the cookie should be "iCloud.test.Feedback" (you can view the complete cookie in the browser dev tools).

Otherwise, checkout the CloudKit Web Services Reference, it provides information about how to form a request that needs authentication. Here is a link to the specific info about web authentication: [Getting the Web Authentication Token](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW3)

Be sure to note that the token needs to be URL encoded. Javascript provides a convenient method for that purpose: `encodeURIComponent(string)`

Comment: Kindly help me by  answering  for the above query.

Comment: Just so you know, that's not how Stack Overflow works.  A) if you have a comment it belongs as a comment, not an answer.  B) one question per Stack Overflow post; if you have a new question you should ask it separately.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for the reply Mr.Billyham, it was quiet helpful for me to perform the task. But while going through the link you had shared I’m able to reach to the Apple Developer sign in page but, once after i login there I’m not able to go further. it is showing an authentication error message and also it is taking quiet a long time for the page to load.

I had followed your instruction by taking the 4th parameter of a JSON response  redirectURL as  ckWebAuthToken 
(Parameters i have received uuid:”6dff555” ,serverErrorCode:”AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED”,  reason : “request needs autherization” ,redirectURL : “https://idmsa.apple.com/auth/oauth_token=95695kdfjdjdjgfdsds” )

from the reply you had shared with me and also i would like to hear your suggestion on I have checked post message radio button for API Access menu  apart Custome URL  in iCloud developer dashboard, so i this a reason for the error message to pop up or any suggesions ?.